# SQL DB directly on Android Device (so no network connection necessary)

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android App which has a section called favorites. In the section the user can take a picture and name it the way he wants, and look at it later on.

To save the Image paths I want to create a DB. Since the Images shall be stored on the Device, my DB should at best, need no network connection.

So my Question is, if SQL (already used it with PHP) could do the job, or do I need something special?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: Android supports SQLite. There's loads of documentation on it.

Comment: I am well aware that Android supports SQL, I was asking if the DB could be directly on the device, so I don't need a network connection

Comment: Yes you do not need internet it will be stored locally

Comment: @Adrian: read suggestions more closely. SQLite != SQL, it is a file based RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Please understand this in simple words. Android has a ability to have a built-in SQL. This SQL is called `SQLite`.

Now as I believe you need to save only the path of the Images in the table of the `SQLite`. May I suggest some tutorials to get you started.

Link for those tutorails

- [Google](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)
- [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)
- [AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)
- [TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm)

PLUS: You do not need `PHP` or anything as I see here.